# Установка FLTK. CLion. MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, g++, clion

Собственно есть fltk-1.3.5, как мне это прикрутить? Нужно что-то собирать? Если да, то как? Или просто прописать в cmake файле нужно что-то? Если да, то что?

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, Вам необходимо:

1.Указать путь к директориям с исходным кодом (include's)

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    # ...
    # путь то директории include FLTK
    )
```

2.Указать путь к библиотекам FLTK

```
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    # ...
    # путь до директории с скомпилированными библиотеками FLTK
    )
```

3.Указать, с какими именно библиотеками FLTK Вы хотите линковаться

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    # имена библиотек
    )
```

Comment: Я видимо делаю что-то не так. 
Пишу: target_include_directories(fltk_test PRIVATE
        "C:\\Program Files\\fltk-1.3.2"
        )
Ответ: Cannot specify include directories for target "fltk_test" which is not
  built by this project.

Comment: Это значит, что проект, который Вы собираете - не fltk_test.